# Is it possible to query the un-modified data within an Oracle (9.2) Transaction?

Tags: oracle

I'm looking at doing a data-fix and need to be able to prove that the data I have intended to change is the only data changed. (For example - that a trigger hasn't modified additional columns that I wasn't expecting)

I've been looking at Oracle's Flashback Query process, which would be great, except that this is not enabled on the database in question.

Since this check would be carried out prior to committing the transaction, Oracle must have the "before" information squirreled away somewhere, and I wondered if there is any way of accessing this undo information?

Otherwise, I would potentially have to make a temporary copy of each table and do a compare between the live table and the backup, which may also result in inconsistencies between the backup query time and the update transaction time.

While I'm expecting the answer "no", I'm hoping someone can point me in a better direction than that which I appear to be headed at present.

Thanks!

Comment: It should be easy to query if you have any triggers on your table.

Comment: A trigger could modify completely different tables, possibly in a different database (or do crazy things like send email...), not just other columns.

Comment: Not relevant to answer but `Oracle's Flashback Query` will only work in Oracle 10g onwards. You question says you have `Oracle 9`, so that part is not applicable anymore

Comment: @XING - I've been reading about flashback query in the 9.2 manual, so I had assumed that it would work - if only it was enabled - and I'd never get a change like that agreed at this point anyway.

Comment: Aha..that's good then. Whenever DML occurs on a table oracle makes a copy in redo logs until its not commited but thats not available to user. So i dont think there exist a way.